# How to prove the following operator is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Related to this question:[To prove it is a Schauder basis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4121089/to-prove-it-is-a-schauder-basis)

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\{e_k\}$ be a Schuader basis. For $n\ge 1$ define the operator $P_n:X\to X $ by
$$
P_n(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_ke_k)=\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_ke_k
$$
where for any $x\in X$, $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_ke_k$.

How to show that there exists $M>0$ so that $\|P_n\|\le M$ for every $n\ge 1$?

My proof:

Let $x=\sum_{k\ge 1} \alpha_k e_k$ and $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k e_k$. Since $\{e_k\}$ is a Schauder basis, then as $n\to \infty$
$$
\|x-x_n\|\to 0
$$

Then there exists $M>0$ so that $\|x_n\|\le M$.

So we have
$$
\sup_{n\ge 1}\|P_nx\|=\sup_{n\ge 1}\|x_n\|\le M
$$

By uniform boundedness principle,
$$
\sup_{n\ge 1}\|P_n\|<\infty
$$

Comment: You have to use the fact that you deal with basis, i.e. the series on the right is convergent and that $X$ is Banach space, This is a general fact known under uniform boundedness principle name.

Comment: If $P_n$ are bounded then the norms $\|P_n\|$ are uniformly bounded as the sequence $P_n$ tends strongly to the identity operator. The fact that $P_n$ is bounded is associated with the boundedness of the coordinate functionals $\sum_k\alpha_k e_k\longmapsto \alpha_ne_n.$ This is a nontrivial fact.

Comment: @Salcio Can you please check my proof? Does it look ok?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Can you please check my proof? Does it look ok?

Comment: Doesn't the uniform boundedness principle require that the operators which it is applied to are bounded, which is exactly what you want to prove?

Comment: @Gerd, as far as I remember uniform boundedness principle requires pointwise boundedness and, based on it, derives boundedness of norms. The idea is to create closed sets which sum up to the whole space and then use Bair's lemma.

Comment: @Hermi - Yes, uniform boundedness principle implies  that pointwise implies norm boundedness. So, you are good.

Comment: @Salcio Uniform boundedness principle requires pointwise boundedness of a familiy of continuous linear operators. Consider for example a discontinuous linear operator $T$ and set $A_n:=T$ for each $n$. Then the family $\{A_n:n\}$ is trivially pointwise bounded but not uniformly bounded since each operator is unbounded. I think the proof of Hermi is not correct.

Comment: @Gerd So how to fix it? We need to prove $P_n$ is bounded?

Comment: @Gerd Show that there exists $M>0$ so that $\|P_n\|\le M$ for every $n\ge 1$

Comment: @Gerd We can show that $P_n$ is bounded since $\|P_n x\|=\|x\|\le M$ so $\|P_n\|=\sup_{\|x\|\le 1}\|P_nx\|\le M$.

Comment: How do you know that $P_1$ is bounded ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Ok. I am confused now. So how to fix the proof?

Comment: @Hermi Yes, you need to prove that the operators $P_n$  are all bounded. The key to that is to prove that $|||x|||:= \sup_{1\le k < \infty} \|P_k(x)\|$ is an equivalent norm on $X$. Then $\|P_n(x)\| \le |||x||| \le M\|x\|$ for some constant $M$. You can find the details for example in the book of I. Singer: Bases in Banach spaces I, §3, p.17, Proposition 3.2. The complete proof is a bit technical.

Comment: @Gerd For the proof of $|||x|||$ is an equivalent norm, can we say " since the space $X_n=span\{e_1,\dots e_k\}$ is finite dimensional, then all norms defined on $X_n$ are equivalent. Then $|||x|||$ defined on $X_n$ are equivalent?

Comment: @Gerd Also, does this $\sup_{n\ge 1}\|P_nx\|<\infty$ imples $\|P_n x\|\le M_x\|x\|$? So it seems that $P_n$ is bounded?

Comment: For each fixed $x$ the quantity $\sup_n\|P_nx\|$ is well defined as the sequence $P_nx$ is convergent. However it does not imply that $P_n,$ $P_1$ in particular, is a bounded operator